# Android class with context in object field in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, kotlin

Is it ok to have a property in object class in Kotlin that has a context in it? In Android it is a bad practice to put context related objects in static fields. Android studio even highlights it and gives a warning unlike Kotlin where there is no warning.
Example object:

```
object Example {
    lateinit var context: Context

    fun doStuff(){
        //..work with context
    }
}
```

Comment: *in java it is a bad practice* no ... it is related to Android not java ... which implicates that it is also bad in Kotlin ...

Comment: also there are different Contexts ... Application, Activity, Service ... storing Application's Context is "less bad"(you can do it better but there should be no Context leaks) than storing Activity or Service context

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Changed it to Android.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `object`s are singletons, they have a single static instance. So if you give them a `context` property, you're still storing a `Context` in a static way.

This will have the exact same consequences as putting a `Context` in a static field in Java.

---

If you write the equivalent code that Kotlin generates for an `object` in Java, it will actually result in the proper lint errors:

```
public class Example {

    // Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak 
    // (and also breaks Instant Run)
    public static Context context;

    // Do not place Android context classes in static fields (static reference to 
    // Example which has field context pointing to Context); this is a memory leak 
    // (and also breaks Instant Run)
    public static Example INSTANCE;

    private Example() { INSTANCE = this; }

    static { new Example(); }

}
```

Comment: But why there is no warning then?

Comment: Because google forgot or it is hard to find such situation with Kotlin's "object"... feel free to fill bug report

Comment: Indeed, they probably just haven't added this lint check for Kotlin `object`s yet.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not getting any warning is **because** the android studio **does not have mature lint check rules** for Kotlin being used for android. Once `toolkit team` updates their `lint check rules` for kotlin with android, the warning will appear again.