# Create class extend AsyncTask without leaking context object in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I defined a base class extends `AsyncTask` and have some custom method. I want to create some child classes which `extend` this, and `override` some methods. But by this way, its field will leaks the `Context` object.

```
abstract class ParentTask(context: Context) : AsyncTask<Void, Int, String>() 
{
    ...
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void): String? {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Please tell me why and show me how to implement it in Android Kotlin? I'm very appreciated if there's an example about this.
p/s : I'm searched for this but can't understand. Why using Singleton, or other design pattern

Comment: As long as `context` is `context.applicationContext` you'll leak no activity.

Comment: Do you mean the context in the constructor? How will this be leaked?

Comment: @s1m0nw All View field in this class also have this warning. I don't know exactly how it leak. I think it only happen when define Context in an 'object' in Kotlin

Comment: @EugenPechanec In Android Studio, there's a warning at line :
var context: Context
Somebody tell that let using internal class. But I have any idea about my case

Comment: Show the warning please

Comment: @s1m0nw1 This field leaks a context object less... 
A static field will leak contexts.  Non-static inner classes have an implicit reference to their outer class. If that outer class is for example a Fragment or Activity, then this reference means that the long-running handler/loader/task will hold a reference to the activity which prevents it from getting garbage collected.  Similarly, direct field references to activities and fragments from these longer running instances can cause leaks.  ViewModel classes should never point to Views or non-application Contexts.

Comment: @s1m0nw1 You will find the same question here, but AsyncTask in my case : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44134811/android-class-with-context-in-object-field-in-kotlin

Answer (score 4):

You can't avoid this warning this way, but you can handle that your context is application context and it won't leak:

```
    abstract class ParentTask(context: Context) : AsyncTask<Void, Int, String>() {
        private val context: Context

        init {
            this.context = context.applicationContext
        }

        override fun doInBackground(vararg voids: Void): String? {
            //...
        }
    }
```